# mypy declaring incompatible types, despit the fact that all types are explicit and using Union

Tags: python, mypy, typing

```
from enum import Enum

class MyEnum(Enum):
    FIRST = 1, 'first'
    SECOND = 2 , 'second'

__myenum_int_ref: Dict[int, MyEnum] = {k.value[0]: k for k in MyEnum}
__myenum_str_ref: Dict[str, MyEnum] = {k.value[1]: k for k in MyEnum}
__myenum_str_ref.update({k.name: k for k in MyEnum})

__flags_ref: Dict[Union[Type[str], Type[int]], Dict[Union[str, int], MyEnum]] = {
    str: __myenum_str_ref,
    int: __myenum_int_ref,
}
```

When I run mypy I get this error

```
function.py:14: error: Dict entry 0 has incompatible type "Type[str]": "Dict[str, MyEnum]"; expected "Union[Type[str], Type[int]]": "Dict[Union[str, int], MyEnum]"
function.py:15: error: Dict entry 1 has incompatible type "Type[int]": "Dict[int, MyEnum]"; expected "Union[Type[str], Type[int]]": "Dict[Union[str, int], MyEnum]"
```

I have explicitly described that the keys can be of type int and of type str, I inserted in the dictionary a key type int and a key type str.

I know that it is correct because on python 3.10, using `Type[int|str]` is the preferred way and mypy does accept it perfectly, and it is the "sugar syntax" added so you don't have to write `Union[Type[int], Type[str]]`.
But I need to use python 3.9, and I am stuck with the use of Union for types, and mypy is complaining that it is incompatible even when I am dealing with explicit types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your value type is `Dict[str, MyEnum]` or `Dict[int, MyEnum]`, you should use `Union[Dict[str, MyEnum], Dict[int, MyEnum]]` instead of `Dict[Union[str, int], MyEnum]`:

```
Dict[Union[Type[str], Type[int]], Union[Dict[str, MyEnum], Dict[int, MyEnum]]]
# in Python3.9
dict[Union[type[str], type[int]], Union[dict[str, MyEnum], dict[int, MyEnum]]]
# in Python3.10+
dict[type[str] | type[int], dict[str, MyEnum] | dict[int, MyEnum]]
```

**Update:**

Using `Protocol`, you can pass the mypy check:

```
from typing import Protocol, TypeVar

_T = TypeVar('_T')


class FlagsRef(Protocol[_T]):

    def __getitem__(self, item: type[_T]) -> dict[_T, MyEnum]: ...


__flags_ref: FlagsRef = {   # pass
    str: __myenum_str_ref,
    int: __myenum_int_ref,
}

int_ref: dict[int, MyEnum] = __flags_ref[int]   # pass
```

Comment: `type[str | int]` is **not** the same as `type[str] | type[int]` (or this is not obvious and requires proof at least: for example, given arbitrary generic class `G`, we have `(G[T1] | G[T2]) <: G[T1 | T2]`, they have different meaning), although `mypy` treats them in similar way. Here it should be `type[Union[int, str]]` in the former case for consistency (or `type[str] | type[int]` in the latter).

Comment: Mypy requires that `Union[Type[str], Type[int]]` be instead written as `Type[str | int]`, and in places where you have `Dict[Union[str, int], str]` to instead write `Dict[str | int, str]` I dont know why it does, mypy isnt fond on explaining its reasoning, it just expects you to comply

Comment: Anyway, MyPy still dont like that

`function.py:14: error: Invalid index type "Union[str, int]" for "Union[Dict[str, PersistentDictFlags], Dict[int, PersistentDictFlags]]"; expected type "str"`

`function.py:15: error: Invalid index type "Union[str, int]" for "Union[Dict[str, PersistentDictFlags], Dict[int, PersistentDictFlags]]"; expected type "int"`

For some reason it does not like that you are passing `int` to an `Union[Type[str], Type[int]]` key...

Comment: @LucasCoppio I have found a way to pass the mypy check. Hope it is useful to you.